# What kind of user interaction and visual transforms do I need?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I will apologize in advance if this appears vague.  The problem I am having is that I am not certain how to properly articulate what I want to achieve into the correct question.  I will try to describe my goal.

This is for a windows 8 tablet app.  Imagine a set of rectangles across the top of the screen, much like piano keys. The user will drag a key down a little  (I can do this).  Then touching the top end of the rectangle they will drag their finger in a circle around it, as they do so the rectangle will fan out into an actual circle.  Then when finished they would drag the top around the opposite way closing it.  Sort of like one of those Japanese hand fans.

What do I search for or how do I phrase this in such a way that will point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, its maddening not being able figure out what I need search for.

Comment: Do you want to have the rectangle transform into a sector (i.e. a pie slice) and then have the sector expand as the user drags their finger, by progressively increasing the angle at the centre of the sector?

Comment: I think starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj883700.aspx) will give you ideas and keywords to search

Comment: Somewhere in the [faq], no, [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), it says something to the effect of "share your research, what you tried and why it didn't work. This helps prevent people from repeating work that you've already done." No offense, but this site gets a ton of questions every day and quite often they are one- or two-liners claiming to have searched half the internet. For obvious reasons, that doesn't fly anymore so it really helps to be more specific. Also, try not to get discouraged on your first try participating on SO.

Comment: dandan78 - You know what, you're right.  It was late and I took it too personally.  And you are correct, it is in the FAQ.  I should have known better.  I'll just work on creating better and questions and answers.  Thanks for the perspective shift!  (No sarcasm implied or intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I should have phrased this question better.

To provide an answer to my query:

Shape manipulation of the type I am describing I believe can be accomplished a couple of ways.  One possibility is through the use of animations.  The other method (which I am currently pursuing) involves the use of the Polygon shape and the ManipulationDelta event.  By utilizing the rotation event it is possible to adjust the points of the shape itself instead of applying the actual rotation.